# how to calculate gbp charges in stripe payment api

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Please let me know how to calculate gbp charges in `stripe` payment api.

When I pay 77 Gbp, then it converts as follows:

> Amount: £0.77 GBP
>
> Fee:  £0.22

Could you please help me understand this calculation?

```
$payment = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
           'amount' => 77,
           'currency' => 'gbp',
           'customer' => 'cus_9pI6dChsVygOLm',
           'capture' => true,
           'description' => 'Testing response',
    ));
```

Comment: Did you specify "currency" => "gbp" ?

Comment: yes i have specified "currency" => "gbp"

Comment: please help me to this calculation.

Comment: Your code looks correct, you may want to contact them.

Answer (score 3):

When you pass the amount to Stripe as a charge it is in cents. Therefore to actually charge 77GBP you'll need to times that amount by 100.
See the Stripe documentation and how it mentions that it's in cents: 
https://stripe.com/docs/quickstart#charging-your-customer-immediately

And then the fee is what Stripe charges you for the the transaction based on the amount.